# VS2012 Exporting the "User Settings"

Tags: c#, xml, settings.settings

I am trying to find a good system to store settings that can be changed by the user.
I've tried to use an `.ini` file but with this I can't seem to save and load some values, like colors.
I've also tried to use `XML`, but that slowed me down so much to a point that it became useless.

I wanted to know if it's possible to export the `Settings.settings` from the Properties project. If so, how to export to an `XML` file?

**Here is some code I use to call the settings**

```
        button1.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.ColorINFO;
        button2.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.ColorWARNING;
        button3.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.ColorServer;
```

**Here is the code I use to save the settings**

```
        Properties.Settings.Default.ColorINFO = button1.BackColor;
        Properties.Settings.Default.ColorWARNING = button2.BackColor;
        Properties.Settings.Default.ColorServer = button3.BackColor;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: They should be in the saved in the app.config.

Comment: @DanielA.White Then, when I export the file I don't see the values change if I change a value in the "Settings.settings" file.

Comment: How are you Exporting the code FoxyShadoww? show some existing code that you are using

Comment: Yes, for more example 1. [How To: Write User Settings at Run Time with C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755.aspx)
2. [Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
3. and a simple query in google [C# setting save](https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=C%23+setting+save&oq=C%23+setting+save&aqs=chrome.0.57j58j60l2j62l2.8695&sugexp=chrome,mod=2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) **EDIT**: Here the [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/4f3e1f68-d19c-4a43-a650-bd4afa9c4593) that you're trying to retrieve the values

Comment: @FoxyShadow a settings.settings file is a code-time feature.

Comment: @DanielA.White But isn't it possible to use this instead of a third-party dll that handles xml files? Because I don't know if there are much options left :(.

Comment: You need to look at the user.Config file look at this explanation 

`Application-scoped settings and the default user-scoped settings are stored in a file named application.exe.config, which is created in the same directory as the executable file. Application configuration settings are read-only. Specific user data is stored in a file named user.config, stored under the user's home directory.`

Comment: @DJKRAZE I see... Then is it you think possible to "export" those settings and re-apply it in the new updated version? Might be a stupid question, else I don't know how I could save and load settings :(.

Comment: perhaps there are setting in the user.config and to update that real time or at time of save I would investigate looking into updating XML file using XPATH perhaps..

Comment: @DJKRAZE I think I will indeed just use a XML file, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using an XML editor which allows to read and write to any XML file, with this I can make a custom settings file. Thank you all for your help :).